# Color slider puzzle

Tags: iphone

I was going through the iPhone samples available [here](http://hoangtuanonline.com/mad/iPhone%20documents/books/object-c%20books%3B%20iphone%20books/Iphone%20Books/Iphone%20DevCenter%20&%20GL%20Specs/iPhone%20Sample%20apps.pdf).

There is one sample code named ***Color Slider Puzzle***, but the link to the download is not working.

Does anyone have a working download link to this sample code?

Answer (score 0):

This specific sample may have been removed by Apple, but you will find plenty of samples here:

> **[iOS Reference Library: Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code)**

Comment: yes  0xA3, i already search there, actuallly i was looking for slider app code, ithought, if some1 would still hv it at some other place.